# MIPS pipeline registers length (IF/ID, ID/EX, EX/MEM, MEM/WB)

Tags: mips, pipeline, cpu-architecture, machine-code

I am currently studying for my Computer Architecture exam and came across a question that asks to illustrate (bit by bit i would assume) the values contained in the mips pipeline architecture after the 3rd stage of the `sub` (before the clock commutes) given the following instructions.

```
add $t0,$t1,$t2 
sub $t3,$t3,$t5 
beq $t6,$t0,16 
add $t0,$t1,$t3
```

I am not asking for the solution to this problem however after some research i haven't had much success wrapping my mind around it so i am asking for some help/advice.

Firstly i still don't have a clear understanding of the size of the pipeline registers (IF/ID, ID/EX, EX/MEM, MEM/WB). I do understand that they contain the control unit codes for the next stages and that they contain the result of the previous stage so that it can be passed in to the next one.
So that would be (please correct me if i'm wrong) +9 for ID/EX, +5 for EX/MEM and +2 for MEM/WB but i haven't managed to find a clear schema of the data that we can expect these registers to contain.
Also, i figure that we would need to use HW forwarding to forward the result of the first `add` to `beq` (because of `$t0`) and to forward the result of `sub` to the last `add` (because of `$t3`). Does this factor in to what is contained in the registers?

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks lots.

Comment: You have to show us what the pipeline looks like from your textbook. There are many ways to design the pipeline. I guess you're using a 32-bit MIPS ISA where the GPR registers and memory addresses are 4-byte in size, right? I think I can answer the question, but I just want to make sure I get right.

Comment: Hi Hadi, Yes i can confirm that it's a 32-bit MIPS ISA with 4-byte addresses.
Thanks lots for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of each of these intermediate registers is to hold data that *might* be needed in the immediate next stage or in later stages. I'll discuss one possible design, but there are really many possible designs as I'll explain.

In the fetch stage, the next instruction to be execute (to which the current PC points) is fetched from memory and PC is updated to point to the next instruction to fetch. Therefore, IF/ID would include one 4-byte field to hold the fetched instruction. There are two ways to calculate the new PC: current PC + 4 or PC + 4 + offset in case of a branch. If the fetched instruction is itself a branch instruction, then we would need to pass the new PC so that the branch target address can be calculated in the EX stage. We can add a 4-byte field in IF/ID to hold the new PC value to be passed to the EX stage through the ID stage.

In the decode stage, the opcode and its operands are determined. The opcode is at a fixed location in the instruction in MIPS. An MIPS instruction may operate on a single source register, two source registers, one source register and a sign-extended 32-bit immediate value, a sign-extended 32-bit immediate value, or no operands. We can either prepare only the required operands for the EX stage based on the opcode or prepare all the operands that *might* be required for any opcode. The latter design is simpler, but it requires a larger ID/EX register. In particular, two 4-byte fields are required to hold two possible source register values (the values are read from the register file in the decode stage) and a 4-byte field for the possible sign-extended immediate value. No opcode will require all of these fields, but let's prepare all of them anyway and store them at fixed locations in the ID/EX register. It simplifies the design.

We to also pass the new PC value calculate in the fetch stage to the execute stage just in case the opcode turns out to be a branch. The branch target address is calculated relative to the current PC value (the PC of the instruction following the branch in static program order). There are two possible design here: either add a bus from the new PC field in IF/ID to the EX stage or add a field in ID/EX to hold the new PC value, which can then be accessed in the EX stage. The latter design adds a 4-byte field in ID/EX.

The EX requires the opcode from the ID stage. We can choose to pass only the opcode rather than the whole instruction. But then later stages might require other parts of the instruction. Generally, in RISC pipelines, it preferable to pass to make the whole instruction available to all stages. In this way, all parts of an instruction are already available when changes are made to any stage of the pipeline in the future. So let's add a 4-byte field to ID/EX to hold the instruction.

The EX stage reads the operands and the opcode from the ID/EX register (the opcode is part of the instruction) and performs the operation specified by the opcode. The EX/MEM register has to be big enough to hold all possible results, which might include the following: a 4-byte value computed by the ALU resulting from an arithmetic or logic operation, a 4-byte value representing the calculated effective address for a memory load or store operation, a 4-byte value representing the branch target address in case of a branch instruction, and a 1-bit condition in case of a conditional branch instruction. We can use a single 4-byte field in EX/MEM for the result (whatever it represents) and a 1-bit field for the condition. In addition, as before, we need a 4-byte field to hold the instruction. Also for store instructions, we need another 4-byte field to hold the value to be stored. One possible alternative design here is that rather than storing the 1-bit condition and 4-byte branch target address in EX/MEM, they can be passed directly to the IF stage.

In the MEM stage, in case of a branch instruction, the branch target address and the branch condition are passed back from EX/MEM to the IF fetch to determine the new PC. In case of a memory store operation, the operation is performed and there is no result to be passed to any stage. In case of a memory load operation, the 4-byte value is fetched from memory and stored in a field in the MEM/WB register. In case of an ALU operation, the 4-byte result will be just passed to a field in the MEM/WB register. In addition, as before, we need a 4-byte field in MEM/WB to hold the instruction.

Finally, in the WB stage, the 4-byte result whether loaded from memory or computed by the ALU is stored in the destination register. This only occurs for instructions that produce results. Otherwise, the WB stage can be skipped.

In summary, in the design I've discussed, the sizes of intermediate registers are as follows: IF/ID is 8 bytes in size, ID/EX is 20 bytes in size, EX/MEM is 25 bits in size, and MEM/WB is 8 bytes in size.

The design decision of whether a field is required in an intermediate register to hold some value or whether it can be passed directly in the same stage to the logic that requires the value is a "circuit-level" decision. If the signals can be guaranteed to not be corrupted, and if it feasible or convenient to add a dedicated bus, they can be directly connected.